# Creating custom button in Delphi with different actions

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am creating a custom component, a button-switch like this :

[image: Switch button image]

In my "form activate" function, I wrote a `for` loop in which I call 3 times the button function with a different position parameter like : `SwitchButton(30);` where 30 is the top position.

What I want to do is assign at these 3 buttons different actions, here some code.

Code for button creation :

```
procedure TFMain.SwitchButton(posPulsante: Integer);
var
  i:                      Integer;
  posDescrizionePulsante: Integer;
  strDescrizione:         String;
begin
  posDescrizionePulsante := 32;
  lastPressed := 1;

  Pulsante := TPanel.Create(FMain);
  BordoPulsante := TShape.Create(self);
  LevaPulsante := TPanel.Create(self);
  DescrizionePulsante := TLabel.Create(self);

  //Proprietà Descrizione
  with DescrizionePulsante do
  begin
    Parent := PComandi;
    Top := posDescrizionePulsante;
    Left := 100;
    Caption := 'Visualizza finestra utenti';
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Size := 12;
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
    Font.Color := clWhite;
  end;

  //Proprietà Pulsante
  with Pulsante do
  begin
    Parent := PComandi;
    ParentColor := false;
    ParentBackground := false;
    BevelOuter := bvNone;
    Color := clWhite;
    Width := 57;
    Height := 25;
    Top := posPulsante;
    Left := 20;
    Visible := true;
  end;

  //Proprietà Bordo
  with BordoPulsante do
  begin
    Parent := Pulsante;
    Align := alClient;
    Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Brush.Color := RGB(122,136,201);
    Pen.Color := clWhite;
    Pen.Style := psSolid;
    Pen.Width := 3;
  end;

  //Proprietà Leva
  with LevaPulsante do
  begin
    Parent := Pulsante;
    ParentBackground := false;
    ParentColor := false;
    BevelOuter := bvNone;
    Color := clWhite;
    Cursor := crHandPoint;
    Width := 23;
    Height := 13;
    Top := 6;
    Left := 28;
    LevaPulsante.OnClick := SwitchState;
  end;
end;
```

Code for creating Button object :

```
procedure TFMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  posPulsante: Integer;
begin
  posPulsante := 30; 
  for i := 1 to  3 do
  begin
    SwitchButton(posPulsante);
    posPulsante := posPulsante + 50;
  end;
end;
```

Would be nice to have some : if SwitchButton 1 is clicked then do something. if SwitchButton 2 is clicked then do something else.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking?

Comment: Normally you would use the OnClick event of the control for this: assign different methods to the OnClick to do different things.

Comment: Only... there is no indication that these buttons have any *OnClick*.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an acceptable use of the `Tag` property. You can specify some number, for example the index of the for loop, in each of the panels:

```
procedure TFMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  posPulsante: Integer;
begin
  posPulsante := 30; 
  for i := 1 to  3 do
  begin
    SwitchButton(posPulsante, i {For example, add the tag as extra parameter});
    posPulsante := posPulsante + 50;
  end;
end;
```

And then set that tag in the button, here using the added parameter `indexPulsante`.

```
procedure TFMain.SwitchButton(posPulsante: Integer; indexPulsante: Integer);
var
  i:                      Integer;
  posDescrizionePulsante: Integer;
  strDescrizione:         String;
begin

   ...

   LevaPulsante.Tag := indexPulsante;
end;
```

And then, in the event handler (which I think you called `SwitchState`), you'll have the `Sender`, which is the control that was clicked (the panel, in your case).

```
procedure TFMain.SwitchState(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case (Sender as TComponent).Tag of
    1: ShowMessage('You clicked the first. Do something.')
    2: ShowMessage('Do something else.')
  else
    ShowMessage('You clicked another button than 1 or 2');
  end;
end;
```

NB: `Tag` is introduced in TComponent and therefore also available in TPanel. In the code above I only typecast to TComponent, because it doesn't matter that it's a panel to get the tag, but if you want to use other properties, a more specific cast may be needed. I like to keep the cast generic, to make it easier to make changes like switching to another type than TPanel, for instance when you actually gonna make a component out of this (inherited from TCustomControl?), or use a third party component.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i thought also to use tags and now i just tried.. But it doesn't work. When i click switch 1 it stills drives the third switch.

Comment: I've used the tag property in this fashion multiple times. It will work. You might step through your code.